# Notepad++ in-file keyword autocomplete

Tags: notepad++

Is there a plugin to Notepad++ that will auto-complete keywords found in the current file?

```
function getSomeThing() {
    return 'something!'
}
console.log(getSomeThing(|      <---here, auto-complete should offer getSomeThing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the built-in Notepad++ settings. Within settings, check out the `Backup/Auto-Completion` tab -> `Auto-Completion` section:

[image]

Here's it in action:

[image]

Comment: what is "function completion"?

Comment: I haven't tried it directly, but I think it then only auto-completes words that resemble functions (possibly as defined per-language), versus all words in a file; in my example above, auto-complete will be done for *all* words (including `function`, `return`, `something`, etc).